# Java Network Programming in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I new to java network programming.When i type following code in netbeans.Netbeans reports getByName(),getHostName() and getHostAddress() as compile error can not find symbol,by underlining as red color.I use netbeans IDE 7.1.1.I do not know is there any additional class library to import or something.
Please help me with this.

```
import java.io.*;  

import java.net.*; 


public class javanet {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("www.bit.lk");
            System.out.println("Host Name: " + ip.getHostName());
            System.out.println("IP Address: " + ip.getHostAddress());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious if you were practicing and created your own class called `InetAddress`, in the same package is _this_ `javanet` class. This would cause a compile error. Try to import the fully qualified class name instead of the wild card and see what happens `import java.net.InetAddress;`

Answer (score -1):

looking at the java code, this is totaly fine (it compiles for sure). Try to clean up your project and rebuild it.